What happens with lazy-loaded images above the fold?
Could somebody explain, what happens, if all images, even those above the fold, have attribute loading="lazy"?
Do browsers have any logic to decide to not lazyload images, which are immediately visible? Or are in fact even above the fold images lazyloaded, causing layout shifts?

If an image as the attribute loading="lazy" that tells the browser to only load the image when it's in the viewport.

Do browsers have any logic to decide to not lazyload images, which are immediately visible?

When the browser first starts loading a page it has no idea what is in the viewport, and what is not. To know that it has to layout the page, which requires CSS and any render-blocking JavaScript.
So the most immediate impact of using loading="lazy" for in-viewport images is you delay starting to download the images, until it's laid out the page. This may not sound like much of a delay but has a noticeable impact on metrics like LCP.
So you should only apply loading="lazy" to images you know will be off-screen.

Or are in fact even above the fold images lazyloaded, causing layout shifts?

You should not depend on images loading to avoid layout shifts. They can cause  layout shifts whether lazy loaded or not, as you can't guarantee the images will be downloaded before the other content is drawn to screen. Instead you should tell the browser for the image dimensions are so it can reserve the space before it's downloaded.

I always feel that loading multiple images at the same time may cause them to compete for bandwidth. Is it a good idea to add loading="lazy" to images that are NOT the LCP, even if they are above the fold, to give the LCP image some fresh air?

While LCP is important, other on-screen images can also be important so no I wouldn't do that. In fact the browser will typically treat images as lower priority anyway (think of loading=lazy as "even lower") so for the absolute best option you should use fetchpriority=high for important images (LCP, logo), loading=lazy for off-screen images, and neither for anything in between: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rAf_Yx7R_g&t=212s

Thank you for the advice. Cool video btw :)
